# Why cast the NSNumber contents of an NSMutableArray when retrieving the intValue?

Tags: objective-c, types, casting, nsarray

In some sample code, an `NSNumber` is added to a mutable array:

```
// In the .h, as an instance variable:
NSMutableArray *sequence;

// In the .m file:
sequence = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];

[sequence addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:123]];
```

Then later on, when the integer is needed, it uses:

```
[(NSNumber *)[sequence objectAtIndex:aCounter] intValue]
```

I just wonder why the cast `(NSNumber *)` is needed?  Because the program runs fine without it, too.  Is it just a good practice? If so, what can it prevent from happening? If there is a bug so that one element is not an `NSNumber *`, then casting it can create strange behavior too.

Answer (score 1):

Casting only makes the compiler believe that the object (which is returned as of type `id`, i. e. generic object type with no other information!) is actually an `NSNumber`, so that it can identify correclty its `intValue` etc. methods. It doesn't make things differ at runtime. If the object is not an NSNumber, then it will crash at runtime, with or without the casting.

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to do it without the casting, the casting just makes it explicit that you treat it as an NSNumber, if you have a bug and this is not an `NSNumber` (or more precisly, don't respond to `intValue`) you'll get some odd behavior anyway.

Answer (score 1):

//In objective-C any object can send message to any other object.
//SO here both statmenst are perfectly valid ,but

[(NSNumber *)[sequence objectAtIndex:aCounter] removeFromSuperview]; //This throws warning and lets u know removeFromSuperview shpuld'nt be called

[[sequence objectAtIndex:aCounter] removeFromSuperview];//here u wont get any warnig

Answer (score 1):

> I just wonder why the cast (NSNumber *) is needed?

It's not needed *if the signature of the selector that's actually called at runtime is visible to the translation, and all selector signatures visible to the translation match for the selector that's called*.

You're probably thinking *"What? That's complicated! That's also error prone, especially as my programs evolve!"*

If multiple selector signatures for the same selector are visible and you message `id`, then you should expect undefined behavior because objc collections aren't typed and the compiler may not match the correct selector (if your warning level is high and your includes are all correct, you can see a warning about this).

The simple way to avoid this is to reintroduce the correct type by assignment:

```
NSNumber * n = [array objectAtIndex:i];
int a = [n intValue];
```

or by casting:

```
int a = [(NSNumber*)[array objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
```

so the compiler can match the selector appropriately for the type, and also warn you when the object may not respond to a given selector, or if the parameters or return types do not match, or if the interface of the type you cast it to is not visible in the translation -- after all, you should have an idea of what the collection contains.

Introducing that type safety properly is a very good practice.

Answer (score 0):

The cast is just needed to stop the compiler from complaining that it's not sure you know what you're doing.

One of the things that the compiler does for you as it compiles is to check whether the interfaces for the recievers of messages say that they respond to the messages you're sending (`intValue` in this case). The interface of `NSNumber` does indeed say that it responds to `intValue`, but the return type of `objectAtIndex:` is `id`, which is a generic pointer. The compiler has no way to know what the type of the object at the other end of that pointer is -- that won't be known until runtime.

The cast tells the compiler that you do indeed know the type and that it doesn't need to warn you (or, in some cases under ARC, give an error) about the fact that it's not sure if the receiver of the message responds.

Note that if you changed the class of the cast to something that didn't respond to `intValue` (such as `NSDate`), the compiler would gripe at you, **but** if the object really was still an `NSNumber`, the message would still succeed at runtime. Casting can't change the type of the object; it is simply an annotation for the compiler.*

---

*In some cases, it can also increase the readability of your code, too.

Comment: hm... but if the cast is removed, the compiler doesn't give a warning either...  (I am using Xcode 4.3.2)...

Comment: It wont give because u can pass message to any object.But try to call other method which is not defined in NSNumber with casting it will throw warning

Comment: @Jeremy: You're right; I got a little carried away in describing casting in general.

Comment: @Jeremy: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488079/why-do-i-need-to-cast-before-a-method-of-an-item-of-a-nsarray-can-be-called for an example of a problem caused by not casting.